# Add a new row in bounded dataGridView on button click

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have a datagridview and filling it using datatable as datasource .

I want to add a new row on button click , using method to first unbound it and then add new row in it . As the following :

```
 dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = false; 
 dataGridView1.DataSource= null;
 dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
```

But instead of adding new row below the existing row , it clears the existing data in row. I think present that row as new row.

how can I add the new row below the existing row and keep the data in other rows safe .

NOTE -- columns of datagridview view are custom columns  .

Answer (score 0):

If you need to keep safe the existing rows, you must retain the datasource. Can try the following please?

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    DataTable dt;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        InitDataGridView();
    }

    private void InitDataGridView()
    {
        dt = new DataTable();

        dt.Columns.Add("A"); dt.Columns.Add("B");

        var dr = dt.NewRow();

        dr["A"] = "A-init"; dr["B"] = "B-init";

        dt.Rows.Add(dr);

        dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var dr = dt.NewRow();

        var counter = dt.Rows.Count;

        dr["A"] = "A-" + counter; dr["B"] = "B-" + counter;

        dt.Rows.Add(dr);
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks @husky, but it is working same as of DGV1.Rows.add(); i. e clearing already exited data in DGV .

Comment: Clearing happens when dataGridView1.DataSource= null; You need to retain the datasource and add new row to the table, to keep safe existing rows. Would be great if you explain the idea why you need to unbound the datasource.

Comment: I only want to add new row each time button is clicked , I googled a lot and found  that new row added  by unbound datagridview . I really don't have any idea that by doing so  will delete the existing data . no other reason to unbound DGV .

Comment: Just add new row to the bound table, Can you check the updated code please?